# mwaa restart functionality for requirements.txt updates

Tags: airflow, requirements.txt, mwaa

Every time our team puts another requirements.txt file for our MWAA environment, it requires a restart.

Regardless of the environment being in a `PENDING` or `UPDATING` state, I can *still* access the UI and run/monitor DAGS. I expect something to at least be unavailable or locked during this process from a user perspective.

So, my questions are: in the MWAA way of things, *what* exactly is being "restarted" during this process and *why* is applied to the entire so-called MWAA environment?

Comment: I can only assume that its HA mode. Meaning that old webserver will be killed only after new one starts so UI is always available. From Airflow point of view if you add package all components need to have it so everything need to be restarted  I think that for this specific question you are better to contact MWAA support as its about the core internals of thier product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Airflow DAG processor`, `Airflow workers` and `Airflow scheduler` are reboot
but not `Airflow web server`
This can be confirmed checking their respective logs.

Beware, some long-running task can fail during a reboot.